# What is MEAN (on Ubuntu)?

Tags: linux, application, terminology

This might initially seem like the sort of question that is easy to Google, but it's not.  Instead of useful results, you get [things like answers to the question "What does Ubuntu mean?"](https://www.google.com/#q=what+is+MEAN+on+Ubuntu&safe=active), or ["what does ~ mean in a Linux shell?"](https://www.google.com/#q=what+is+MEAN+Linux&safe=active) or ["mean, median, mode, and range"](https://www.google.com/#q=what+is+MEAN+&safe=active).  Every different attempt I've made fails because of the normal meaning of "mean" and how Google interprets that.

The context in which I've encountered this is my [Digital Ocean control panel](https://cloud.digitalocean.com/droplets/new):

[image: Digital Ocean control panel for creating a new droplet (VM)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the explanation by digital ocean (since i think that's where you got the screenshot from):

[what is mean on ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/what-is-mean-on-ubuntu)

> It's an application stack based on NodeJS and MongoDB. You can read more about it here: http://mean.io/.

[MEAN](http://mean.io/) is a boilerplate for applications using [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/), [Express](http://expressjs.com/), [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) and [Node.js](http://www.nodejs.org/).

Oh, and btw I've googled that by using `""`. Like this: [googling "mean on ubuntu"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22MEAN%20on%20Ubuntu%22&oq=%22mean%20on%20&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0l2.5068j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Since I assumed that (unlike Ruby on Rails or something) Ubuntu is incidental--that is, MEAN does not require Ubuntu (they say "MEAN on Ubuntu" simply because they're giving you an Ubuntu VM with MEAN)--I didn't think of searching for the whole thing in quotes.  But you're right, since other people were confused by the very same Digital Ocean panel button as I was, there you have it: relevant search results.